# Выбор типа проекта при его создании в Visual Studio 2012 и 2015?

Tags: c#

Всем привет, хочу в Visual Studio 2015 сохдать ASP.NET MVC - но у меня в списке выбора типа проекта есть только "Пустое приложение ASP.NET" почему так? как добавит еще дополнительно типы проектов ? А в VS 2012 вообще нет раздела Web ?
VS 2015 - Comunity VS2012 - Express

Comment: если память не изменяет, и там, и там ASP.NET MVC шаблон устанавливался отдельно, но подробностей уже не помню. Гляну конечно, если ни кто больше не отпишется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В 2013 это делалось так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вводим в поиск ASP.Net и вуаля(Вжух!!!)

Answer (score 1):

Согласно этой статье [Missing MVC template in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015), Вам может помочь установка пакета Web developer tools, если он у Вас еще не установлен.